# Add calculated columns based on conditions of other column on select SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to add some columns based on calculations depending on the conditions of other columns.

For example, I have this:

```
EVENT_ID               Color              WinnerPrice            WinnerCount 0 to 5                              5 to 15                              15 to 50                              BSP
---------------------- ------------ ------------- ---------------------- ----------- ----------------------------------- ------------------------------------ ------------------------------------- ----------------------
138386456              red 1                      8.707157072            1           sum of BSP when BSP between 0 and 5 sum of BSP when BSP between 5 and 15 sum of BSP when BSP between 15 and 50 8.707157072
138386458              blue         1             101.7549557            1           sum of BSP when BSP between 0 and 5 sum of BSP when BSP between 5 and 15 sum of BSP when BSP between 15 and 50 101.7549557
138386460              yellow 1                   7.532110284            1           sum of BSP when BSP between 0 and 5 sum of BSP when BSP between 5 and 15 sum of BSP when BSP between 15 and 50 7.532110284
138386464              other fields 1             52.34970073            1           sum of BSP when BSP between 0 and 5 sum of BSP when BSP between 5 and 15 sum of BSP when BSP between 15 and 50 52.34970073
138386468              other fields 1             35.86681076            1           sum of BSP when BSP between 0 and 5 sum of BSP when BSP between 5 and 15 sum of BSP when BSP between 15 and 50 35.86681076
138386468              other fields 1             44                     1           sum of BSP when BSP between 0 and 5 sum of BSP when BSP between 5 and 15 sum of BSP when BSP between 15 and 50 44
138386470              other fields 1             32                     1           sum of BSP when BSP between 0 and 5 sum of BSP when BSP between 5 and 15 sum of BSP when BSP between 15 and 50 32
138386474              other fields 1             55.55523634            1           sum of BSP when BSP between 0 and 5 sum of BSP when BSP between 5 and 15 sum of BSP when BSP between 15 and 50 55.55523634
```

Image version:

[image]

How could I do this in a performant way? I have to add several of this type of calculated queries, but I can't wrap my head around how to do it in a way that is performant (I thought it might be done with rollup? but not getting it)

I also tried doing a scalar function for it, but it seems it is just moving the logic out of view as it's still a very poor performant.

The condition would be a sum of the BSP field grouped by a field that is not shown now, let's say

- column between 0 to 5 should have sum of bsp when bsp between 0 and 5 grouped by when color = 'red'
- column between 5 to 15 should have sum of bsp when bsp between 5 and 15 grouped by color = 'blue'
- column between 15 to 50 should have sum of bsp when bsp between 15 and 50 grouped by color = 'yellow'

An example of the existing query for getting everything between 0 and 5 is:

```
SELECT 
    tblData.MENU_HINT, tblData.EVENT_NAME, 
    SUM(tblData.BSP) AS [Sum], 
    COUNT(tblData.ID) AS [count], 
    AVG(tblData.BSP) AS AVerage, 
    tblData.EVENT_ID
FROM 
    tblData
WHERE 
    (((tblData.BSP) > 0 AND (tblData.BSP) <= 5))
GROUP BY 
    tblData.MENU_HINT, tblData.EVENT_NAME, tblData.EVENT_ID;
```

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not as images. (And I can't read that tiny image text...)

Comment: you're totally right, thank you for the tip, I'll edit now to show it that way, meanwhile, if you click the image will give you the full size image.  but I'll edited as suggested

Comment: What is "color"?

Comment: I fixed it, is one of the columns, is an example to show some of the conditions I will have to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want conditional aggregation.  I'm a little confused on which calculations you actually want, but the idea is:

```
SELECT t.MENU_HINT, t.EVENT_ID, t.EVENT_NAME,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.BSP >= 0 AND t.BSP < 5 THEN t.BSP END) as sum_0_5,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.color = 'Red' AND t.BSP >= 0 AND t.BSP < 5 THEN t.BSP END) as sum_red_0_5,
       . . . And so on for the calculations you want
FROM tblData t
GROUP BY t.MENU_HINT, t.EVENT_NAME, t.EVENT_ID;
```

Comment: I got this, but will it be performant? I have to calculate over a huge amount of records and for several columns (about 80)
I know that from the get go is not the best approach, but I think going bigger here will be less performant

Comment: @Baldie47 . . . As performant as any aggregation.  I don't think you have much choice fro what you want to do.

Comment: well, it does solve the issue, I can't complain, heheheh I think though about over(partition by) function... I'm trying to figure out how to use it but I'm not sure

Comment: @Baldie47 . . . Window functions are going to be more expensive, if you actually need to do an aggregation.